# API Manager 1.10 - Is there a way to monitor back end health?

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

I actually try WSO2 API Manager in our IT and I can't found how to monitor backend WS.

Is there a way to have an alert (trace/mail/...) when :

- the time response of a webservice is too high?
- the Webservice is unavailable (or http code isn't 200) ?

This tool seems great but I need a monitoring part...
Perhaps I simply miss it...
Any helps ?
If you already use WSO2 APIM in production how do you manage this part?

Regards,
Mike

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By Using APIM and CEP integration, you can achieve this requirement. APIM can be configured to publish thrift events into CEP and then CEP can process these events to provide necessary alerts and notifications as required.

Please refer below document for [APIM and CEP integration](http://wso2.com/library/articles/2015/03/article-get-near-real-time-api-traffic-notifications-with-wso2-api-manager-and-wso2-complex-event-processor/).

Answer (score 0):

WSO2 API Manager has following statistics monitoring

- API Subscriptions: Number of subscriptions per API (across all
  versions of an API)
- API Usage: Number of API calls being made per API
  (across all versions of an API)
- API Response Times:
- API Last Access Times: The subscribers who did the last 10 API invocations and the APIs/versions they invoked
- API Usage by Resource Path: Usage of an API and from which resource path (per API version)
- API Usage by Destination: To see destination-based usage tracking, you must first enable it. See API Usage by Destination.
- API Usage by User: Number of times a user has accessed an API
- Faulty Invocations: The number of API invocations that failed to reach the endpoint per API per user In a faulty API invocation, the message is mediated though the fault sequence. By default, the API Manager considers an API invocation to be faulty when the backend service is unavailable.

For more information, please see https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM1100/Viewing+API+Statistics

Comment: Thanks for you answer...
I already manage to have this works but that's not my question.
Is there a way to be warn when an problem occurs ( back end ws down, time response too high,...)

Comment: If you have enabled statistics with WSO2 DAS as above, these kind of alerting can be configured in DAS side by creating Siddhi Execution Plans [1]  and analyze the problems occurred in real time. Then you can publish alerts using event publishers [2].

[1] https://docs.wso2.com/display/DAS300/Creating+a+Standalone+Execution+Plan

[2] https://docs.wso2.com/display/DAS300/Event+Publisher+Types

Comment: That can't be a acceptable solution because we warned about problem (WS down for example) only after someone call it (and failed).

In another word, we must wait someone to fail to be warn about problem.
Thanks for the answer. I close the question.
Regards,

Answer (score 0):

For our public hosted version of API Manager - [WSO2 API Cloud](http://wso2.com/cloud/api-cloud) - we simply set up Pingdom for both the gateway and the web UIs and exposed the public dashboard at the [SLA & Support page](http://wso2.com/cloud/sla-support/). Pingdom also has email, sms, etc. alerts when response times get over 30 seconds.

Internally we also use various server monitoring tools like icinga.